# PHPmailer list from mysql, not sending to all

Tags: mysql, phpmailer

I am running a PHPmailer Send() from a list of 600+ members but only a selected few receive the email anything from 40 to 100 and the selection is random throughout the database

I presume it has something to do with PHPmailer not keeping up with the speed of requests

On each 'for' I reset the 'to' with ClearAddresses(), the body is less than 100 words and no attachments

Any ideas

Comment: As a side note; is there a particular reason not to use a mailing list service instead of building the functionality yourself? Many (cheap) web hosts are blacklisted and mail from there will show up in the spam folder of the recipients more often than not.

Comment: No it's not that, I record each successful send in an array and it's the array that is incomplete (and the people don't receive the mail

Answer (score 0):

Use Thread or give some sleep time

Answer (score 0):

Did your hostingprovider regulate the Mail-traffic?
In other way, you can replace the mail() function with an Array. At the end of the script, you can print_r($Array); and you can validate your loops.

Comment: No it is actually in the send that is failing

Comment: Ok. Do you have a Linux-Server? You can look in the /var/log/maillog